# MERGE on Oracle table with high hit rate of updates

Tags: oracle, merge

I was trying to find some details on the performance of the Oracle MERGE statement versus the traditional Select Insert/Update but wasn't able to find something with my situation.

I am using a MERGE statement in my code as an UPSERT statement, example below:

```
    MERGE INTO table_a a USING dual d ON (a.keyone='a' AND a.keytwo='b')
    WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET a_column='c'
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (keyone,keytwo,a_column) VALUES ('a','b','c')
```

This will always be used to update only one record in a table that has almost 70 million rows.  But I am running into some blocking/lock issues.

I was wondering, if another process is issuing updates at the same time against this "table_a", example

```
    UPDATE table_a SET a_column='c' WHERE keyone='d' AND keytwo='e'
```

but **never** against the same keys, could it be that the MERGE statement takes a long time to execute against a fairly large table, thus blocking updates that are coming subsequently to rows with other keys? (will always be different keys for the update statement)

These would all be happening around the same time (one service issuing merges and the others issuing updates to the table_a)

Am I doing the wrong approach? Should I just be doing a SELECT and then based on result either INSERT or UPDATE for a table this big?  I thought that blocking only occurs if 2 statements are trying to access the same row resource.

EDIT: Forgot to mention, table_a does not have many columns, it is essentially

```
    key_one number
    key_two number
    key_three varchar(1)
    creation_date_time, mod_date_time
```

Answer (score 0):

I say put the MERGE in. If you start having problems, replace it with INSERT/UPDATE logic if needed; but until you have a problem you don't have a problem. Do the simplest thing that could possibly work. And I wouldn't do a SELECT first. Execute the UPDATE, check SQL%ROWCOUNT (or whatever), and then do the INSERT if needed.

Comment: hi Bob, thanks for the reply!  Today I am using the MERGE which is where I ran into the problem where I had locking occur, although both processes aren't ever accessing the same record.  This led to my only guess being that MERGE took a while and the UPDATE was being put on hold, but I thought Oracle might be able to handle it with no problem.

Comment: Then try replacing the MERGE with UPDATE/INSERT and see if that takes care of it.